# Why doesn't "Jobs" let you filter for full-time vs. part-time jobs?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I was wondering if Jobs will add the ability to filter for full-time vs part-time jobs? If not, is there a reason that this doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 6):

Most jobs on the board are either full-time, contract or internship positions. You can already filter by those things using the background category:

[image: Background Filters]

We don't currently support part-time because not enough jobs provide it so it doesn't make for a worthwhile filter. It's possible we'll re-evaluate this in the future if employers express an interest in it.

Comment: I'm sure employers will never be interested in this only employees. Part time is basically a perk like better health care etc.

Comment: This wouldn't be a perk, but a requirement for me due to disability. :/

Answer (score 4):

The full-time checkbox in the background filter does nothing. You get full-time jobs even if unchecked.

Maybe there are not a lot of part-time jobs, but there are certainly many people looking for them.
Adding a meaningful filter would certainly help your user base.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see what this answer at least means:

> We don't currently support part-time because not enough jobs provide it so it doesn't make for a worthwhile filter.

It reads if this would be a huge task, even if it's at least `only` one additional field for a filter.

Even if there are only a few offers for part-time...
1st: there are any, and
2nd if you can filter for Full-Time it make absolutely sense to even be able to filter for part-time

So in my opinion it is a must-have in a job-board - as it is a huge improvement for people who searching for a part-time job.