# Allow filter for number of full-time hours

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

It would be nice to be able to filter jobs based on the number of full-time hours they want you to work. Some European companies are moving toward 32 or 30 hours full-time. It would be nice to be able to find those more easily.

The answer to this question may be just like [why part-time searching is not available](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373753/why-doesnt-jobs-let-you-filter-for-full-time-vs-part-time-jobs). If it really is that companies don't want or care about that feature, that's fine. I understand that they are the customer of Stack Overflow jobs, not me.

Comment: 30 hours _including_ slacking off on Stack Overflow?

Comment: `Many European companies are moving toward 32 or 30 hours full-time`

European here. This is a lie (and please stop spreading this misinformation). The common work week here is 37-40 hours (usually depending on if lunch is work time or not) But working in Europe, specially in independent jobs like Software Engineering, you're expected to manage your own time, and for example, if you're responding to emails as part of your commute, nobody expects you to be in the office for 8 hours afterwards.

Comment: _Many_? {{reference needed}} and please help to update https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-time. Or please confirm it at https://skeptics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Europe here as well - I work 40h+ in the office - what's above 40h goes to a time account and can be deducted when needed. 30 or 32 is _rare_ even IG-Metall has 35h/week to 40h depeding on the  
collective bargaining agreement - but they get more money/h as well - power of labor unions.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Wow, you get to deduct time later from time spent earlier over 40h work weeks? I need to migrate to Europe!

Comment: @tyler I collect up to 60h -and If I need a day off I can "pay" 8h from that-but thats company-rules - not law. depending on the employer they might pay your over-hours out or simply rule you're not allowed to do them and void the time you  have above 8h

Comment: @PatrickArtner In the US we have paid time-off (PTO) accrual in pretty much all companies. You can use that time to take off of work and still be paid your full wages but it is sometimes very minimal (e.g. two weeks a year including major holidays)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen and others: I got my info from a few news articles here. Looks like it's mostly Germany and France that are lower hours:
https://www.forbes.com/sites/niallmccarthy/2018/01/08/the-countries-working-the-most-hours-every-year-infographic/
https://www.usnews.com/news/best-countries/articles/2016-09-02/hardest-working-countries-ranked-by-hours-worked-per-year
Still would be a nice bit of info to know.

Comment: @Cœur, that list is for the legal defined minimum "full-time" status according to governments. The effective full-time amount for each country is very different and set by individual company requirements. The US set theirs at 30, but you will be hard pressed to find a company actually offering that. I have changed my answer to read "some" instead of many... since a lot of folks seem to take issue with that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback! This isn’t something we’ve seen many requests for, but we’ll definitely keep an eye out in future conversations, especially with customers in European markets.

If we see a lot of companies offering positions with a varying number of hours, we’ll look into building something out here. Without this, a filter wouldn’t really be effective since we wouldn’t have any listings that fit the criteria.