# Please add Job-Type "Part-time"

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I have a feature-wish for the Stack Overflow job-filter.
What I sorely miss is to be able to filter for "part-time" jobs:
[image]

There are Part-Time-Jobs in the list, but as you see in the screen-shot you can only add this keyword to the search field (and this does not work very well).

So I hope y'all will add the Job-Type "Part-time".

Comment: This [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373753) is basically the same, but I'm not sure it counts as a duplicate since this is a [feature-request] while that's a [discussion].

Comment: @cigien:  I would count it as a dupe but I would also hope that *this* question could be answered, so that this question could be used as a dupe target for the other one.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, agreed, that direction would be better. Since you have a hammer in every mandatory tag (I think), and MSO posts don't need to have an answer to be used as a target, you can just go ahead and hammer that one. In fact, it seems the other post is already attracting fresh answers, so hammering it straight away would probably be a good idea, even if this one is as yet unanswered.